# copying files from sdcard to android internal storage directory

Tags: android

I have created a directory in android internal storage using following lines:

```
File directory = getDir("template", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I need to add some files in this 'template' directory from sdcard, what is the way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try using this method. in that you should give source and destination file names.

```
private boolean copyFile(File src,File dst)throws IOException{
        if(src.getAbsolutePath().toString().equals(dst.getAbsolutePath().toString())){

            return true;

        }else{
            InputStream is=new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(dst);
            byte[] buff=new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len=is.read(buff))>0){
                os.write(buff,0,len);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770004/how-to-move-rename-file-from-internal-app-storage-to-external-storage-on-android was also helpful