# How to copy a file from sdcard to system

Tags: android

I want to copy a file from sdcard to /system/etc. Below is the code in my application:
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /sdcard/settings.txt > /system/etc/Settings.txt"
It doesn't works.
I run cmd on pc, it works well. I did as below:
  adb shell
 $cat /sdcard/settings.txt > /system/etc/Settings.txt

Why doesn't the cmd work in java code? What's my mistake? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This does not work on your android device because of a permission issue.

Comment: Do you know what permission must be added?

Comment: Your device must be rooted before you can do it the same way AFAIK

Comment: Yes, that's right. But the command doesn't work in java code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [copying files from sdcard to android internal storage directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036381/copying-files-from-sdcard-to-android-internal-storage-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remount the system partition in read-write mode, something like this (the block device will almost certainly be different):

```
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

This is not something a normal application would ever, ever do. It will also only work on a phone that has root access (you need to do this via `su`)

Comment: I also used this code in my application, but it doesn't work. Do you know what permission is needed?

Comment: You need to be running as the root user. I recommend reading up on unix operating system user permissions. These are very different from your application permissions. You are almost certainly not doing something which requires you do do this. Try opening a question about what you really *need* to do.

Comment: To note. If you are going to do anything with root, then checkout RootTools: http://code.google.com/p/roottools/