# Save picture while Camera is in stopPreview mode

Tags: java, android, android-camera

**BACKGROUND**
Hey so I have a camera that I have implemented myself in code. This means I access and control the camera hardware and use it to save pictures. I can save the picture using the Camera.takePicture() function when the camera is **running**: running means Camera.startPreview();

**PROBLEM**
My problem is that I want to be able to save the image also when the camera image is **frozen**: frozen is when Camera.stopPreview(); is called.When frozen I can see the image in my layout but how do I access it? Where is the image saved so that I might be able to modify it later?

Thanks in advance!

**------------------Update 1**

```
    jpeg bla;
public class jpeg implements PictureCallback{

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        g_data = data;
    }    
}
```

This is part of my code. Here I am trying to write the data that would originally be saved to a global variable. However the value of g_data remains null and I am unable to set a breakpoint inside the onPictureTaken() call back function.

**------------------Update 2**

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        // generate the folder
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MirrorMirror");
        if( !imagesFolder.exists() ) {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        // generate new image name
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH_mm_ss");
        Date now = new Date();
        String fileName = "image_" + formatter.format(now) + ".jpg";
        // create outstream and write data
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        outStream.write(data);
        outStream.close();          
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // <10>
        //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Exception #2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {}
```

I used this code previously to save the file from the camera onPictureTaken() function. The key here is the byte[] data which I need to save and save later. However like I said I just get a null when I check it in the debugger.

Comment: You want to take picture without preview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the exact way to do this is to take the picture just before stopPreview() and save it to a temporary file. Actually with this implementation you never call stopPreview()(otherwise it will crash) since the takePicture() function stops the preview automatically.

```
try {
        File temp = File.createTempFile("temp", ".jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now that we have the temporary file saved we will access it later and move it to our new desired  file location.
[How to copy file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770004/how-to-move-rename-file-from-internal-app-storage-to-external-storage-on-android)

```
temp.deleteOnExit();
```

be sure to call deleteonExit() so that Android deletes the file after the app is closed(if so desired).

Answer (score 1):

Camera.takePicture never looks at the view you specified as previewDisplay. Actually, it isn't an ImageView, but a SurfaceView, and there are no API to read pixels from it.

You can call takePicture() preemptively just before you stopPreview(). Later, if you find out that you **don't** need the picture, just discard it.

Comment: ditto! this is what i am trying to implement right now. Actually the more i go into this the more i realize i have no idea how takePicture() works. sry if this is a bad question.
-------> I am trying to add code into the takePicture in jpegPictureCallback class but and then use the debugger but it never stops inside the function. I should be able to save the byte[] data from the takePicture easily enough. will report back

Comment: I posted the Update 1 and as i said I am unable to save the data passed from the onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera). If I include the save to file code the image is saved. I dont know whats happening..