# File.renameTo return false

Tags: android, file, file-rename

I want to rename my png file. Image current path like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/sample.png
```

I want to save this image under app's file directory. I give write external storage permission on runtime.

```
File toFileDir = new File(getFilesDir() + "images");
if(toFileDir.exists()) {
    File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/sample.png");
    File toFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "images/sample-1.png");
    file.renameTo(toFile);
}
```

renameTo returns false. But I couldn't understand the reason.

Comment: both files are on the same device? if not, `renameTo` will not work

Comment: yes, same device.

Comment: `Log.d` the values of `file` and `toFile`

Comment: @pskink /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/sample.png. toFile /data/user/0/com.example.user.packageName/files/sample-1.png

Comment: so how do you know they are the same physical devices?

Answer (score 0):

Internal and external memory is two different file systems. Therefore renameTo() fails.

You will have to copy the file and delete the original

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770004/how-to-move-rename-file-from-internal-app-storage-to-external-storage-on-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try the following method:**

```
private void moveFile(File src, File targetDirectory) throws IOException {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (!src.renameTo(new File(targetDirectory, src.getName()))) {
            // If rename fails we must do a true deep copy instead.
            Path sourcePath = src.toPath();
            Path targetDirPath = targetDirectory.toPath();
            try {
                Files.move(sourcePath, targetDirPath.resolve(sourcePath.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to move " + src + " to " + targetDirectory + " - " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (src.exists()) {
            boolean renamed = src.renameTo(targetDirectory);
            Log.d("TAG", "renamed: " + renamed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question states that this permission is already in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting `false` because I had the debugger attached, turning it off fixed the issue